# how to get new coordinates with width, length and angle known?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, plane-geometry

I am having trapezoid with three coordinates known. So I need to create the 4th coordinate with length, width and angles I am having. You can assume this problem with $△ADC$ from trapezoid. The model comes as differently expected . The Law of cosines gives the angle but it should be applied to local coordinates of the model. Right side I am showing with arrow pointed as wrong object which i am getting. Even if I rotate the object or flip it, the coordinates should not get wrong. They should get adjusted with the object's coordinates, width, angle and length.

`newWidth2` is $AB$, `newLength` is $AD$. Point $C$ need to be created from $A$, $D$ with $∠A$ or $∠D$ also. `Math.Pow` is "to the power of" and `2` is it's square.(for who can't understand this notation).

```
//Initially I will have Coordinates for C but later I should remove them and create from the model width and heights.
            //distance formula
            newWidth2 = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(CoordX3 - CoordX5, 2) + Math.Pow(CoordY3 - CoordY5, 2));
    //from the formula ->  b2 = a2 + c2 - 2acCos(B)
        diagangle = Math.Acos((Math.Pow(newWidth2, 2) - Math.Pow(newdiagonal, 2) - Math.Pow(newLength, 2)) / (-2 * (newdiagonal) * (newLength)));
//I am getting this C coordinates as wrong.
     //for getting C (third coordinates)            
        xcoord3 = CoordX5 + (newWidth2 * Math.Cos(diagangle));
        ycoord3 = CoordY5 + (newWidth2 * Math.Sin(diagangle));
```

[image]

Comment: If you know which sides are parallel to each other you can use the the length of unknown diagonals to find the forth point

Comment: yeah I already got the diagonal length but not able to trace it's coordinates and getting some other points especially if the entire object changes it's angle. Need for  the model which can be placed anywhere on the plane.

Comment: without knowing the 3rd coordinate point how can I calculate diagonal? The diagonal point varies according to the Width2 height. I can consider Width2, Length, angle and A,D coordinates.

Comment: with only 3 points it is impossible to find a unique forth point because there is a whole line that will make the shape trapezoid. If you don't have any other information aside from the points you can just decide one the length

Comment: I know width, length and angles of ADC and DAC. Are they not enough?

Comment: so you have the points $A,B,C$ and  width, length and angles of $ADC$ and $DAC$, and you are looking for the point $D$?

Comment: I need new coordinate based on angle ADC. looking for point C. I will have width of DC and length AD.

Comment: if I understand correctly the mistake you had is that there are $2$ triangles that have this angle and the points $A,C$, you should take the other one

Comment: I need to construct DC based on angle ADC, length AD and Width of DC given.